Can we publish compose multiplatform iOS on app Store?
As we all know that now we can develop iOS applications in Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) with shared UI or using Compose Multiplatform (CMP).
Now CMP is currently in Beta so can we publish compose multiplatform iOS application to the app store. Is there anyone who has published it successfully while it is already in beta ?

AFAIK, the Kotlin Conf 2024 app was fully written in Kotlin Multiplatform using Compose Multiplatform to share UI. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/kotlinconf/id1299196584

Yes, We can publish iOS Applications that are built using Compose Multiplatform. Multiple applications are available. Markaz is one of them. Appstore: Markaz
